# Solution to $p^n \equiv -1 \pmod d$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Here is an observation I found when fiddling around with numbers:

Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of by $p^n \bmod d$, and if there exists some $k$ that satisfies $3^k \equiv -1\pmod d$, then it seems that $ k = \frac{|G|}{2}$.

For example, the multiplicative group $\{3^n, \times_{\bmod 25}\}$ has order 20, and $3^{10} \equiv 24\pmod{25}$.

Is this true in general? Or does it only works with a set of values? Why/why not?

Thanks! If there is something not clear, pls tell me and I will reiterate what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this is not true, consider e.g. $p=3, d=8$.
If $p$ and $d$ are coprime and $\pm1\pmod d$ are the only solutions of $x^2\equiv 1\pmod d$ (which is for example the case when $d$ is an odd prime power) then this is true. Note that $G$ is a cyclic group generated by $p$. So in particular the order of $p$ is $|G|=:k$. Since $p^{k}\equiv 1\pmod d$, we get $$(p^{k/2})^2\equiv 1\pmod d$$
and hence $p^{k/2}\equiv\pm1\pmod d$ by assumption. Since the order of $p$ is $k$ we then necessarily get $p^{k/2}\equiv -1\pmod d$.
**Edit:** (for the changed question) If $p^k\equiv-1\mod d$, then $p^{2k}\equiv 1\mod d$, so $2k$ is a multiple of $|G|$. If $k$ is minimal, then $k<|G|$, so the only possibility is $k=\frac{|G|}{2}$. If $k$ is not minimal then we might also have e.g. $k=\frac{|G|}{2}+|G|$.

Comment: I apologize that the question is worded incorrectly that lead to a misunderstanding. I have clarified what I really meant in the question.

Comment: $k=|G|/2$ is only true if the $k$ is minimal